# _UILayoutGuide bottomLayoutGuide length is zero

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7

I encounter a very strange behavior in UILayoutGuide. The bottomLayoutGuide.length returns 0 on messaging the length property.

At the same time printing bottomLayoutGuide in the console returns the following:

```
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x9ad9c60; frame = (0 455; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x9ab8200>>
```

It clearly states that the length of UILayoutGuide's frame is 455.

Printing the length directly via

```
p [((_UILayoutGuide*)self.bottomLayoutGuide) length]
```

returns

```
(float) $12 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Tab- or ToolBar is set to translucent or not – an opaque bar's behaviour is comparable to that of one under iOS 6.

> Provides the length, in points, of the portion of a view controller’s view that is overlaid by translucent or transparent UIKit bars

[UILayoutSupport Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILayoutSupport_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

The length of the guide is from the edge it represents. So if the bottom guide is 455px tall, and the view is 455px tall, the guide is 0px long.